# error installing mysql client after installing remi php-mysql

Tags: mysql, php, centos6, yum

after installing nginx with php-fpm thanks to remi repository, I get an error when I simply install mysql client :

```
yum install mysql
```

give me the following result (see bellow).

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.quelquesmots.fr
 * epel: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
 * extras: centos.crazyfrogs.org
 * updates: centos.mirror.crcrepairs.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mysql-libs = 5.1.73-3.el6_5 for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
---> Package mysql-libs.i686 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10) for package: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10 for package: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10) for package: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10 for package: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
---> Package openssl.x86_64 0:1.0.1e-16.el6_5.7 will be updated
---> Package openssl.i686 0:1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libkrb5.so.3(krb5_3_MIT) for package: openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkrb5.so.3 for package: openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libk5crypto.so.3(k5crypto_3_MIT) for package: openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libk5crypto.so.3 for package: openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libgssapi_krb5.so.2 for package: openssl-1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14.i686
---> Package openssl.x86_64 0:1.0.1e-16.el6_5.14 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package krb5-libs.i686 0:1.10.3-15.el6_5.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1(KEYUTILS_0.3) for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-15.el6_5.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libkeyutils.so.1 for package: krb5-libs-1.10.3-15.el6_5.1.i686
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package keyutils-libs.i686 0:1.4-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.73-3.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit) for package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
           Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.38-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               Not found
Error: Package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.38-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               Not found
Error: Package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient_r.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.38-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               Not found
Error: Package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
               libmysqlclient_r.so.16()(64bit)
           Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.38-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

so.. what's the best way for me to solve this issue ?

regards,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Package: mysql-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
>              Requires: libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
>              Available: mysql-libs-5.1.71-1.el6.x86_64 (base)
>                  libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
>              Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
>                  libmysqlclient.so.16()(64bit)
>              **Installed: mysql-libs-5.5.38-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)**

so i guess you simply need:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing MySQL using the remi repo. CentOS 6 wants to install MySQL 5.1 vs 5.5 libs already installed. So you need MySQL 5.5